# Правильность построения предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Более 11 лет проживал в Испании, в 2009 году, когда вернулся в Россию, работаю репетитором и переводчиком.

Если предложение построено не совсем правильно, то что в нем следует изменить?

Comment: Я бы разбил это предложение на два и слегка скорректировал: **"Более 11 лет проживал в Испании. С 2009 года, после возвращения в Россию, работаю репетитором и переводчиком"**. Конечно, можно слить эти два предложения в одно, но это будет читаться чуть хуже.
P.S.: После того, как модератор разблокирует ваш вопрос, оформлю этот комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Суть вопроса абсолютно понятна: автор просит проверить  грамматику и стиль предложения.  Если нельзя просто предложить исправленный вариант, то тогда желательно соблюдение общего требования правки для всех. Нельзя сказать: Я бы так написал... (этот вариант не прошел и был удален). Ответ должен содержать ПОЛНЫЙ АНАЛИЗ допущенных грамматических и стилистических ошибок и вариант их исправления.

Comment: С другой стороны,  предложить корректный вариант правки сложно из-за отсутствия контекста. Возможно, автор должен был сообщить сведения о себе в предельно краткой форме, то есть был ограничен в объеме сообщения. Другими словами, коммуникативное назначение текста неясно.

Comment: Иван, спасибо большое, ваш вариант лучше.

Comment: О хорошем варианте правки. У нас получилось два предложения. В первом говорится о месте проживания, во втором говорится о месте работы (проживание идет как дополнительная вставочная информация). Если убрать  обособленный оборот, то получим: Более 11 лет проживал в Испании. С 2009 года  работаю репетитором и переводчиком. Такой переход можно считать нормальным? А вот в моем удаленном ответе  всё было последовательно: проживание в Испании, возвращение в Россию, работа переводчиком.

Comment: Ребята, спасибо всем.

Comment: Мне очень нравится вот этот вариант —  "Более 11 лет проживал в Испании. С 2009 года, после возвращения в Россию, работаю репетитором и переводчиком".

Comment: @Peter, спасибо за Вашу оценку. Как и обещал, выношу свой комментарий в виде отдельного ответа: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/445619/190680

Answer (score 1):

1. Если в предыдущем предложении вы обошлись без местоимения "я", его стоит употребить, иначе приходится дочитать до слова "работаю", чтобы понять, о ком идет речь (о себе или о другом человеке).
2. Вероятно, речь идёт о работе переводчиком не в отдельно взятом году (так получается в исходном предложении), а *начиная* с 2009 года. Если начало новой работы совпадает по времени с возвращением, уточняющий оборот "когда (я) вернулся в Россию" (= это был год возвращения) можно сохранить неизменным.

Отсюда вариант с минимальными изменениями:

> Более 11 лет **я** проживал в Испании, а **с** 2009 года, когда (я) вернулся
>   в Россию, работаю репетитором и переводчиком.

Answer (score 0):

"Более 11 лет проживал в Испании" — о месте жительства, "с 2009 года...работаю репетитором и переводчиком" — о трудовой деятельности. Почему эти два предложения стоят в одном ряду? Может быть потому, что работа связана с испанским? Тогда надо об этом сказать прямо, а не заставлять читателя гадать. Например: *Более 11 лет проживал в Испании, где в  совершенстве овладел испанским языком. С 2009 года...работаю репетитором испанского языка и переводчиком (с испанского языка на русский).*

По поводу местоимения *я*. Скорее всего, перед нами только отрывок, а в предыдущем предложении уже стоит *я*. Тогда незачем якать в каждом предложении.

**С 2009 года, после возвращения в Россию, работаю репетитором и переводчиком.**

Мне нравится этот вариант. "После возвращения в Россию" — уточняющая конструкция (с 2009 года, то есть после возвращения в Россию).

Answer (score 0):

*К сожалению, немного пропустил тот момент, когда вопрос был разблокирован, но все-таки сдержу свое слово и оформлю мой комментарий к вопросу в виде отдельного ответа.*
Я бы разбил это предложение на два и слегка скорректировал:

> Более 11 лет проживал в Испании. С 2009 года, после возвращения в
>   Россию, работаю репетитором и переводчиком.

Конечно, можно слить эти два предложения в одно, но это будет читаться чуть хуже:

> Более 11 лет проживал в Испании, а с 2009 года, после возвращения в
>   Россию, работаю репетитором и переводчиком.

Comment: Иван, благодарю Вас за столь развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Использую 1-й вариант без слияния в одно предложение. 